# flask how to preserve instance of SQLAlchemyobject

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, global-variables, instance

I want to load a global menu for any template. The structure of the Query is always the same...

```
class ProductCats(db.Model):
   def __init__(self,
              lang=None,
              catname=None,
              catid=None,
              update=False,
              active=False,
              create=False,
              ):

              self.categories = db.session.query(ProductCats, ProductCatsTranslations)
              if lang:
                  self.categories = self.categories.filter(ProductCatsTranslations.language_code==lang)
   
              if catid:
                  self.categories = self.categories.filter(ProductCatsTranslations.catid==catid)
   
              if active:
                  self.categories = self.categories.filter(ProductCats.active==active)
                                                                                                                                                                                           
   
              self.categories = self.categories.filter(ProductCatsTranslations.catid==ProductCats.catid).\
              order_by(ProductCatsTranslations.sort)
   

              self.dicted_by_catid = {}
   
              for c, ct in self.categories:
                  c.ct = ct
                  self.dicted_by_catid[c.catid] = c 

     # then I have a method within this class
     def by_catid(self, catid=None):
          return self.dicted_by_catid[catid]
```

in **init**.py of my flask app

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    from models import ProductCats
    g.productcats = ProductCats(lang=lang)
```

So I can easily access my productcats everywhere on flaskapp. But it initiates one Query everytime instead of getting it from the dictonary "by_catid". I call something like this. e.g. in the template or on views or where ever in this app.

```
g.productcats.by_catid(catid=12).name
g.productcats.by_catid(catid=172).name
```

This produces two Queries instead of one from **init** of ProductCats

When I manually set up the same db.query of **init** of ProductCats() somewhere else in my application e.g. on my homeview I can call the attribute any time without it creates new Query everytime.

There seems to be something special,  that g.object is calling the init method of ProductCats everytime again? But when I add a simple debugoutput in my ProductCats init it appears only ONE time. Also the relationship to ProductCatsTranslation is lazy-joined. Also it works in my homeview when not using flask-global (g).

How would I have my productcats all over the app without generating one Query for every category while I can still use the instance of my Productcats in my templates e.g.

```
g.productcats.by_catid(catid=12).name
g.productcats.by_catid(catid=14).otherattribute
g.productcats.by_catid(catid=12).active
```

Comment: Could you explain what problem are you trying to solve? And why you decided to use `flask.g`? As far as I understand, you want to return different properties depending on the client's request? (lang => name, catid => active, active => something else)

Comment: hey @DanilaGanchar I have a list of pages stored in the MySQL-DB and I want to have a list ob object in each view, because I need the list of pages in each view or in jinja2-templates. Also yes I may want to do some filtering, but as  said I need those pages on every request thats why I put it into g to access those objects globally.